# Совместимость JDK 11 и JRE 8

Tags: java, jdk11

Будет ли приложение, написанное на JDK 11, работать у пользователя, у которого установлен JRE 8? Если нет, то как сделать так? (кроме как устанавливать JDK, который обычный пользователь вряд ли захочет ставить)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если при компиляции приложения была [указана целевая платформа](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJDCID) версии 8 или ниже, то будет. Если выше, то не будет.